# How to get/extract values of a JSON

Tags: go

I'm trying to get values/index/key of a JSON but no success. I found some answers and tutorials but I couldn't get them working for me.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": "3479",
  "product": "Camera",
  "price": "",
  "creation": 04032020,
  "products": [
    {
      "camera": "Nikon",
      "available": true,
      "freeshipping": false,
      "price": "1,813",
      "color": "black"
    },
    {
      "camera": "Sony",
      "available": true,
      "freeshipping": true,
      "price": "931",
      "color": "black"
    }
  ],
  "category": "eletronics",
  "type": "camera"
}
```

I have tried several examples but none worked for this type of Json.

The error I'm getting:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not
>   map[string]interface {}

I believe it's because of `"products[]"` I tried `map[string]interface{}` and `[]interface{}` it compiles but gives me that error afterwards.

Could you give me an example on how I can extract these values?

The code I'm using:

```
//gets the json
product,_:=conn.GetProductData(shop.Info.Id)
// assing a variable
productInformation:=<-product

//prints the json
fmt.Printf(productInformation)

//try to get json values
type Product struct {
  Id string
  Product string
}       

 var product Product    

 json.Unmarshal([]byte(productInformation), &product)
 fmt.Printf("Id: %s, Product: %s", product.Id, product.Product)
```

This code does not panic but it doesn't print all results either so I tried 
 this one below (which was supposed to give me all results) but it panics

```
var result map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(productInformation), &result)

// The object stored in the "birds" key is also stored as 
// a map[string]interface{} type, and its type is asserted from
// the interface{} type
products := result["products"].(map[string]interface{})

for key, value := range products {
  // Each value is an interface{} type, that is type asserted as a string
  fmt.Println(key, value.(string))
}
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing your code. Read the [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) docs and show your code and data structures.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: I just formatted the json but does seem to contain some invalid characters and missing `,`. What is the source of the json?

Comment: Yes thank you. It was my fault, The json is actually correct. It was me doing tests and I mistakenly copied the wrong one. The problem seems to be "products[]". If I don't have that, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add json tag to specify the field name in json as it is in lowercase

```golang
type Product struct {
  Id string       `json:"id"`
  Product string  `json:"product"`
}
```

And in the second case according to json it is a `slice` not a `map` so you need to cast it to `[]interface{}`

```golang
var result map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(productInformation), &result)

// The object stored in the "birds" key is also stored as 
// a map[string]interface{} type, and its type is asserted from
// the interface{} type
products := result["products"].([]interface{})

for key, value := range products {
  // Each value is an interface{} type, that is type asserted as a string
  fmt.Println(key, value)
}
```

Comment: Instead of `var result map[string]interface{}` I change it to `var result []interface{}` ?

Comment: And the creation field in the json is invalid it should either be string or there should not be any leading zeroes

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try it. Yes I just copied the wrong json. But it's working.

Comment: I get this error: `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not string`

Comment: Updated, The value in the products is `map[string]interface{}` so it cannot be cast to string